# Removing characters from a tuple

Tags: python, string, tuples

Im using

```
Users = win32net.NetGroupGetUsers(IP,'none',0),
```

to get all the local users on a system. The output is a tuple,

```
(([{'name': u'Administrator'}, {'name': u'Guest'}, {'name': u'Tom'}], 3, 0),)
```

I want to clean this up so it just prints out "Administrator, Guest, Tom". I tried using strip and replace but you cant use those on tuples. Is there a way to convert this into a string so i can manipulate it or is there an even simpler way to go about it?

Comment: This was my first run in with tuples didn't know you couldn't use these things with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should not end with a comma:

```
Users = win32net.NetGroupGetUsers(IP,'none',0),
```

The trailing comma turns the result into a single item tuple containing the result, which is itself a tuple.

The data you want is in `Users[0]`.

```
>>> print Users[0]
[{'name': u'Administrator'}, {'name': u'Guest'}, {'name': u'Tom'}]
```

To unpack this list of dictionaries we use a generator expression:

```
Users = win32net.NetGroupGetUsers(IP,'none',0)
print ', '.join(d['name'] for d in Users[0])
```

Comment: Nice catch on the extra comma.

Comment: Thanks for everything, it works great. Also, thanks for explaining your answer too.

Answer (score 4):

```
', '.join(user['name'] for user in Users[0][0])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
input = (([{'name': u'Administrator'}, {'name': u'Guest'}, {'name': u'Tom'}], 3, 0),)    
in_list = input[0][0]    
names = [x['name'] for x in in_list]    
print names

[u'Administrator', u'Guest', u'Tom']
```